# Regex get a word inside a text

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

how to get a username who create the game from string below

```
Creating public game [RANDOM TITLE] started by [XXX].
```

RANDOM TITLE => the title of the game is always changing.

i want get `XXX`

try

```
 words = a.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g)
```

its get the `RANDOM TITLE` and `XXX`.
how to only get the `XXX` ?

Comment: Try a regular expression! May take some learning.

Comment: @minitech updated, pliz help me :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about matching only the final substring `started by \[([^\]]+)\]`

[regex101.com/r/kG9qX6/1](http://regex101.com/r/kG9qX6/1)

Comment: thx, can u voteup my question ?
i got votedown, my score too litle
maybe get banned soon. :(

Comment: Actually, I don't know why your question was voted down, I pushed it up!

Answer (score 2):

Why not use Substring if you already know that the sentence always be something like:

```
Creating public game [RANDOM TITLE] started by [XXX].
```

You can do it simply using this line of code:

```
var str = 'Creating public game [RANDOM TITLE] started by [XXX].'
str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1, str.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

Comment: thx, can u voteup my question ? i cant ask question now
i think got banned :(

Answer (score 1):

try

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

then just grab the second value

Answer (score 1):

i got the solution now

```
words = a.match(/[^[\]]+(?=]\.)/g);
```